# How write a unit test for asynchronous Web API

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

I have a project in C# and Framework 6. I have a WEB API to call the methods.
what is the best way to write a unit test for async WebAPI methods?

This is the method I have:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetYears")]
public Task<IEnumerable<Year>> GetYearsAsync()
{
     return reditApplicationsRepository.GetYearsAsync();         
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `await` to do this too.

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task GetYearsTest()
{
    //_sut is the System Under Test,  in this case is an instance of your controller
    var years = await _sut.GetYears();
    //Any Assert that you want
}
```

And to *stub* the return of the method `creditApplicationsRepository.GetYearsAsync();` use this `Task.FromResult(mockReturn)`.

Comment: You need to make `GetYearsTest` async

Comment: Sure my bad, because the `await`.

Answer (score 2):

The key objective of a unit test is to test the functionality of the code inside a method. So async or not should not be particularly relevant functionally.

So I would say do something like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetYearsTest(){
   //This would assume that your web api class has a mockable repository
   var yourClass = new YourClass(new MockRepository());

   //this is going to run your codes synchronously so you can get an immediate result to test on.
   var years = yourClass.GetYears().Result;

   //Run whatever test you want to on this
   Assert.IsNotNull(years);

}
```

If the purpose of running an Async test is to determine if your code is thread safe you will have to get creative to determine how to properly test your code to ensure it is in fact safe. In order for me to assist with that I would need to know more about the repo that is being used here or what variables could potentially get thread locked or result in an error.